# Core Data:Fetch rlelationships or Fetch Main Entity

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an `Entity A` which has **to-many** relationships with `Entity B`.

```
                   Entity A -->> Entity B
```

I need to refer to the count of to-many relationship, at more than one screen. Further, I can remove and add reference to any `Entity B` from `Entity A` multiple times.

Now, the question is : What is the best way to refer the relationship count?

What I observed:?

1] I can make a `count` attribute in `Entity A` and increment/decrement it according to the relationship count and then fetch this attribute on screens I need.

2] I can also get the `count` from count property of `NSSet`(of relationships), this way I do not have to fetch the `EntityA`. I can simply do,

```
      NSSet *set =    EntityA.EntitiesB;
      NSInteger count = set.count;
```

This way also fetch happens but I do not have to create a fetch request again and again for `EntityA`.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to fetch anything, you can create your fetch request with suitable predicate and then use `countForFetchRequest:error:` to get the count. You could also create a fetch request template (`setFetchRequestTemplate:forName:`) and then use `fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:substitutionVariables:` when you need to use it.

Comment: I am going to give it a try and get back to you on this. Thanks.

Comment: Just to note, if you have already fetched 'A' for some other purpose then just count the relationship set.

Comment: Performance wise, which one is better: countForFetchRequest:error: or using count on relationship set? In my view referring to relationship count also make hit on Mangaed Object Context. I need to do this multiple times on different screens so I just want to be sure.

Comment: If you already have the object then the relationship count should be faster. But, I'd encourage you to test it for yourself and to not worry too much about it till you have reason to (from profiling).

Answer (score 1):

Use the count on the relationship. This pattern will also fit better when integrating the relationship into the UI (for example, number of rows in a table view), and is the method seens in apple's sample code.  Creating a count attribute would most likely just add unnecessary complexity to your model.